# Kick feature only works with one user Python socket chat

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, tkinter, chat

This is tkinter socket Python chatroom where users can send messages to each other.

The problem that I have is that when I use this code:

```
kick = input("Enter address you want to kick: ")
if addr[0] != kick:
    conn.close()
```

to kick the user it works the first time but when I try to use it again the `kick` input doesn't show up. So what I want is that after one user has been kicked I want it to give me the option to kick another user.

## Server.py

```
import socket, threading, json

host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 4000
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((host,port))
s.listen()
clients = {}
addresses = {}
print(host)
print("Server is ready...")
serverRunning = True



def to_json(p):
    return bytes(json.dumps(p), "utf8")


def handle_client(conn):
    try:
        user_name = conn.recv(1024).decode('utf8')
        conn.send(to_json({'CONNECTED':user_name, 'JOINED':list(clients.values())}))
        #welcome = 'Welcome %s! If you ever want to quit, type {quit} to exit.' % user_name
        #conn.send(bytes(welcome, "utf8"))
        #msg = "%s has joined the chat" % user_name
        broadcast(to_json({'JOINED':user_name}))
        clients[conn] = user_name
        while True:
            found = False
            msg = conn.recv(1024)
            if msg != bytes("{quit}" or '**', "utf8"):
                broadcast(msg, user_name+": ")
            else:
                conn.send(bytes("{quit}", "utf8"))
                conn.close()
                del clients[conn]
                broadcast(to_json({'DISJOINED':user_name}))
                print("%s has left the chat." % user_name)
                break
            if user_name in clients.values():
                conn.send("username has been taken")
            else:
                continue
    except Exception as e:
        print('Exception: {} while connected with user: {}'.format(e, user_name))

def broadcast(msg, prefix=""):
    for sock in clients:
        sock.send(bytes(prefix, "utf8")+msg)

while True:
    conn,addr = s.accept()
    conn.send("You have connected to the server \r\n ".encode("utf8"))
    conn.send("Enter username: ".encode("utf8"))
    print("%s:%s has connected." % addr)
    addresses[conn] = addr
    threading.Thread(target = handle_client, args = (conn,)).start()
    kick = input("Enter address you want to kick: ")
    if addr[0] != kick:
        conn.close()
```

## Client.py

```
import socket,threading,tkinter,json,winsound
tk = tkinter
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)


def echo_data(sock):
   while True:
      try:
         msg = sock.recv(1024).decode('utf8')

         if msg[0] == '{': # JSON Message
            message = json.loads(msg)

            # We don't have the `app` object, therefore you have to handle the message here

            if 'CONNECTED' in message:
               msg_list.insert(tkinter.END, "Welcome {} If you ever want to quit, type quit to exit".format(message['CONNECTED']))
               users_online.connected(message)
            elif 'JOINED' in message:
               msg_list.insert(tkinter.END, "{} has joined the chat.".format(message['JOINED']))
               users_online.joined(message)
            elif 'DISJOINED' in message:
               msg_list.insert(tkinter.END, "{} has left the chat.".format(message['DISJOINED']))
               users_online.disjoined(message)
            else:
               print('FAIL: Unknow Message {}'.format(message))
         else:# TEXT Message
            msg_list.insert(tkinter.END, msg)
      except OSError:
         print('Terminate thread echo_data')
         msg_list.insert(tkinter.END, "Connection got closed, for unknown reason, try to reconnect.")
         connect_button.configure(state=['normal'])
         entry_field.configure(state=['disabled'])
         send_button.configure(state=['disabled'])
         return

def send(event=None):
   try:
      msg = my_msg.get()
      my_msg.set("")
      s.send(bytes(msg, "utf8"))
      if msg == "{quit}":
         s.close()
         top.quit()
   except Exception:
      top.quit()
      pass 

def on_closing(event=None):
   my_msg.set("{quit}")
   send()

def connect():
   port = 4000
   send_button.configure(state=['normal'])
   connect_button.configure(state=['disabled'])
   entry_field.configure(state=['normal'])
   print('Server address:{}'.format(entry_server_address.get()))
   host = entry_server_address.get()
   address = (host,port)
   s.connect(address)
   threading.Thread(target=echo_data, args = (s,)).start()


class LabelFrame(tk.LabelFrame):
   def __init__(self, parent, text):
      self._width = 100
      self._bg = 'white'
      super().__init__(parent, text=text, width=self._width, background=self._bg)
      self.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)

   def joined(self, message):
      global user_online
      print('joined({})'.format(message))
      # Add a `tk.Label(self, ...` and assign `text=<username>`
      user_online = tk.Label(self, text=message['JOINED'],bg=self._bg)
      user_online.grid(row=None, column=None)

   def connected(self, message):
      print('connected({})'.format(message))
      tk.Label(self, text=message['CONNECTED'], bg=self._bg).grid()
      if 'JOINED' in message:
         for user_name in message['JOINED']:
            tk.Label(self, text=user_name, bg=self._bg).grid()

   def disjoined(self, message):
      print('disjoined({})'.format(message))
      for lbl in self.grid_slaves():
         if lbl['text'] in message.values():
            lbl.destroy()


top = tkinter.Tk()
top.title("Chat Room")
messages_frame = tkinter.Frame(top)
my_msg = tkinter.StringVar()
my_msg.set("Type your messages here.")
scrollbar = tkinter.Scrollbar(messages_frame)
msg_list = tkinter.Listbox(messages_frame, height=15, width=100, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.pack(side=tkinter.RIGHT, fill=tkinter.Y)
msg_list.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT, fill=tkinter.BOTH)
users_online = LabelFrame(messages_frame, 'Users online:')
messages_frame.pack()
entry_field = tkinter.Entry(top, textvariable=my_msg)
entry_field.configure(state='disabled')
entry_field.bind("<Return>", send)
entry_field.pack()
send_button = tkinter.Button(top, text="Send", command=send)
send_button.configure(state=['disabled'])
send_button.pack()

le_frame = tkinter.Frame(top)
le_frame.pack(fill=tkinter.X)

entry_server_address = tkinter.Entry(le_frame)
tkinter.Label(le_frame, text='Server address:', width=20, anchor='w').pack(side=tkinter.LEFT, padx=5)
entry_server_address.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT, fill=tkinter.X, expand=True, padx=5)
connect_button = tkinter.Button(le_frame, text='Connect', command=connect)
connect_button.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT, padx=5)

top.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)



tkinter.mainloop()
```

Comment: @furas could you show me how to because when I tried it didn't work

Comment: did you try to use two clients with your server ?  `input()` stops `while True` loop so it doesn't go back to `accept()` and second client may not connect. After you answer in `input()` you go back to `accept()` and then it waits for new client and you also has to wait so you can't seen `input()`

Comment: @furas yep your right when the the second user trys to connect it doesn't work so how would I prevent this?

Comment: don't use `input()`in loop with `accept`. Run `input() in separated thread or run loop with `accept` in separated thread.

Comment: when I disconnect one client and connect new client then I see second input().

Comment: @furas I still can't make it work so could you post an answer on how to do it please

Comment: first: remove `input()` and then many clients can connect. Put this `while True` with `accept()` in function and run this function in thread. Second: create `while True` loop with `input()` but without `accept()` and run it normally. So you will have two loops - one with `accept()` in thread , and one with `input()`

Comment: @furas I still can't do it so could you please post an answer on how to do it please

Comment: @furas also I don't really understand you that's why I want to post the answer

Comment: first part is very easy - put `while True` in function, remove `input()` from  `while True`, run this function in `Thread`. This way many clients can connent at the same time. Second part seems easy too: create `while True` with `input()`. Problem can be how to create - inside Thread - list with all connected users and use this list outside Thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It runs `accept()` in thread and `input()` runs in normal way in `while True`

This way loop in thread can accept many clients and normal loop can run `input()` and wait for answer. Instead of address I use port to keep connection on list and to kick someone. `port` is better because two users can't have the same port but they may have the sam address - ie. you can run two clients in your computer in two terminals and they will have the same address but always different port.

---

EDIT: connection works and you can kick off someone but it may need to encode string to bytes before you send it, and decode from bytes to string when you receive it.

---

```
import socket, threading, json

host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 4000
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.bind((host,port))
s.listen()
clients = {}
addresses = {}
print(host)
print("Server is ready...")
serverRunning = True

def to_json(p):
    return bytes(json.dumps(p), "utf8")

def handle_client(conn):
    try:
        user_name = conn.recv(1024).decode('utf8')
        conn.send(to_json({'CONNECTED':user_name, 'JOINED':list(clients.values())}))
        #welcome = 'Welcome %s! If you ever want to quit, type {quit} to exit.' % user_name
        #conn.send(bytes(welcome, "utf8"))
        #msg = "%s has joined the chat" % user_name
        broadcast(to_json({'JOINED':user_name}))
        clients[conn] = user_name
        while True:
            found = False
            msg = conn.recv(1024)
            if msg != bytes("{quit}" or '**', "utf8"):
                broadcast(msg, user_name+": ")
            else:
                conn.send(bytes("{quit}", "utf8"))
                conn.close()
                del clients[conn]
                broadcast(to_json({'DISJOINED':user_name}))
                print("%s has left the chat." % user_name)
                break
            if user_name in clients.values():
                conn.send("username has been taken")
            else:
                continue
    except Exception as e:
        print('Exception: {} while connected with user: {}'.format(e, user_name))

def broadcast(msg, prefix=""):
    for sock in clients:
        sock.send(bytes(prefix, "utf8")+msg)

#--- new code ---

addresses = dict()

def loop():
    while True:
        conn,addr = s.accept()
        conn.send("You have connected to the server \r\n ".encode("utf8"))
        conn.send("Enter username: ".encode("utf8"))
        print("%s:%s has connected." % addr)
        addresses[addr[1]] = (addr,conn)
        threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(conn,)).start()

threading.Thread(target=loop).start()

while True:
    print(addresses.keys())
    port = int(input('port> '))
    if port in addresses:
        addresses[port][1].close()
        print('kick:', addresses[port][0])
```

Comment: I see you use decode/encode but when I run it I saw error - problem with bytes ans str. I didn't check which line of code made problem.

Comment: I don't know I resolved problem with access and input and I didn't check other problems. Do you get any error when you run it ? If not then there is no need to search solution.

Comment: I did get the error but it doesn't tell me which line it is on

Comment: then create new question on new page and you will have place to put FULL Traceback.